# Grönwall's lemma for $t < t_0$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $T \in \mathbb{R}^+ \cup \{ \infty\}, \,t_0\in [0,T), \,a,b\in L^{\infty}(t_0, T)$ and $\lambda \in L_1(t_0, T), \lambda(t)\geq 0$ for almost all $t\in (t_0, T).$ Then, it follows from $$a(t) \leq b(t) + \int_{t_0}^t \lambda (s) a(s) ds \,\,\,\text{a.e. in} \,\,\,(t_0, T)$$ for almost all $t \in (t_0, T)$ the following: $$a(t) \leq b(t) + \int_{t_0}^t e^{\Lambda(t)-\Lambda(s)}\lambda(s)b(s)ds,$$ whereby $\Lambda(t) := \int_{t_0}^t \lambda (\tau)d\tau.$

Do you know of any version of this result in case $t < t_0$ ?

Comment: The first term of the bound looks incomplete, missing the exponential factor. // For $t<t_0$ the upper bound becomes a lower bound.

Comment: Thanks. I checked it out. No exponential factor is missing. I do not know how the change of the bounds can be just like that, I need an argument.

Comment: You might be right in your original statement, the conclusion I was thinking of works if you get the differential inequality starting from a differential equation.